# How to change order of sub-nav in buddypress

Tags: buddypress

i want to ask that how to change order of sub-nav in buddy press is there any plugin exists?
i have used bp-group-hierarchy plugin when ever i add new tab after group hierarchy all the tabs after it disappears.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your loader page and change the position. You can change the numbers to move it either up or down. The lower the number, the higher up it will be. Hope this helps:

```
$sub_nav[] = array(
        'name'            =>  __( 'Screen One', 'bp-section' ),
        'slug'            => 'screen-one',
        'parent_url'      => $section_link,
        'parent_slug'     => bp_get_section_slug(),
        'screen_function' => 'bp_section_screen_one',
        'position'        => 10
);
```